# log4j rootLogger seems to inherit log level of other logger. Why?

Tags: java, log4j

I've got a log4J setup in which the root logger is supposed to log ERROR level messages and above to the console and another logger logs everything to syslog.

log4j.properties is:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,R

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.SGSearch=DEBUG,SGSearch
log4j.appender.SGSearch=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SGSearch.SyslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SGSearch.Facility=LOCAL6
log4j.appender.SGSearch.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SGSearch.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %m%n
```

In code I do

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("SGSearch");
.
.
.
logger.info("Commencing snapshot index [" + args[1] + " -> " + args[2] + "]");
```

What is happening is that I get the console logging for all logging levels. What seems to be happening is that the level for SGSearch overrides the level set for the root logger somehow. I can't figure it out.

I have confirmed that Log4J is reading the properties file I think it is, and no other (via the `-Dlog4j.debug` option)

Comment: I encountered this same issue/confusion.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023690/why-is-log4j-rootlogger-not-filtering-log-events-according-to-event-level.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The way Log4j chaining works is a bit counter intuitive (to me at least). See [the log4j manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#additivity). If the request level is equal to or above the threshold of the most specific matching logger, it is accepted. Once the request is accepted, it gets handled by the complete chain of ancestors regardless of their thresholds!

To suppress the chaining behavior, add:

```
log4j.additivity.SGSearch=false
```

This will cause requests handled by logger SGSearch to no longer be passed up the chain.

One other suggestion: don't name your logger and appender the same, because at some point in the future you, or a colleague will mix them up. The logger name should indicate which type of logging is handled, the appender name should specify where the logging goes. So in this case I would think 'SGSearch' could be the logger name, and the appender should be called something like 'LocalSysLog'.

BTW: In my opinion you are doing the right thing by restricting the root logger with a high threshold, and lowering it for specific loggers. This avoids clutter from loud libraries (Apache has a few notorious ones).

Comment: It surprises me that Log4j does not apply the log event threshold of parent loggers (where root logger is the top-most parent)  independently of their child loggers.

Comment: Thank you!  Your answer was very helpful.  I refer to your answer in my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023690/why-is-log4j-rootlogger-not-filtering-log-events-according-to-event-level/3024279#3024279 to my similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023690/why-is-log4j-rootlogger-not-filtering-log-events-according-to-event-level.

Comment: "Once the request is accepted, it gets handled by the complete chain of ancestors regardless of their thresholds!"  If this is true, then isn't this a bug in Log4j?  Behaviour that is so counterintuitive must be an error.

Comment: I think it has to do with minimalization of the amount of work that needs to be done per log event. But as I said at the start of my response, it IS a bit counter intuitive at first.

Comment: I now better understand how loggers inherit appenders and though this behaviour did seem strange to me at first, I agree that it is not a bug, but is actually a useful way to reduce the number of appenders one need associate with a chain of loggers.

Answer (score 6):

Quick information about Levels

> **Log4J Levels**
>
> Loggers may be assigned levels. The
>   set of possible levels, that is DEBUG,
>   INFO, WARN, ERROR and FATAL are
>   defined in the org.apache.log4j.Level
>   class.
>
> If a given logger is not assigned a
>   level, then it inherits one from its
>   closest ancestor with an assigned
>   level.
>
> The root logger resides at the top of
>   the logger hierarchy. It always exists
>   and always has an assigned level.

I've changed your sample log4j configuration to work this way:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ALL,R

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.R.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.R.Threshold=ERROR

log4j.appender.SGSearch=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SGSearch.SyslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SGSearch.Facility=LOCAL6
log4j.appender.SGSearch.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SGSearch.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %m%n
log4j.appender.SGSearch.Threshold=DEBUG
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. That worked but I found I did need to add the line "log4j.logger.SGSearch=ALL,SGSearch" as well to the example you gave.

Comment: @AndrewR: Or you could have done this `log4j.appender.SGSearch.Threshold=ALL` but then that would make `log4j.rootLogger` useless (if i'm not mistaken).

Comment: I think this solution is suboptimal. See my suggestion below.

Comment: Well, @Adriaan Koster, the solution helped the questioner and that's what he/she wanted.

Comment: Fair enough. I just happen to think opening up the root logger is a common mistake, due to misunderstanding of the way 'additivity' works in Log4j.

Comment: Setting the threshold of the appender is key here.  I used your answer in my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023690/why-is-log4j-rootlogger-not-filtering-log-events-according-to-event-level/3024279#3024279 to my own similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023690/why-is-log4j-rootlogger-not-filtering-log-events-according-to-event-level.

Answer (score 0):

setting the threshold on a per-appender basis is key here:

`log4j.appender.SGSearch.Threshold=DEBUG`

and

`log4j.appender.R.Threshold=ERROR`

this is a far better solution than the suggestion to disable "additivity" - the problem with that is that anything you want *multiple* appenders to handle will be defeated by it - so you cannot, for example, send anything which is an `ERROR` level message to *both* the console and syslog if you set additivity to `false`...